# manage visibility and invisibility of widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help in show/hide widget based in the space i click

i'm using datepicker bootstrap widget and some other widget

my code is :

```
    <div class="o_datepicker">

            <t t-set="placeholder" t-value="widget.getParent().node and widget.getParent().node.attrs.placeholder"/>
            <input type="text"
                t-att-name="widget.name"
                t-att-placeholder="placeholder"
                class="oe_datepicker_master oe_simple_date"/>
        <input t-att-id="widget.name" type="text"
                t-att-placeholder="placeholder"
                class="oe_hijri oe_datepicker_master"
                />
    </div>
```

when i click in anywhere in that `div` the bootstrap datepicker widget is visible.. i want to restrict that to the first input only, and when i click the second input the widget should be invisible because there is another widget that opens when i click the second input.

Note :The both inputs must be in the same `<div class="o_datepicker">`

Thanks

Comment: Why you are not putting both input in same div it will simplify your code.is there any specific reason to put both input in same div?

Comment: yep ..there is some other things need to be handled ,, they must be in the same div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop event propagation on the second input click:

```
$(".o_datepicker input:last").click(function(event) {
    //Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, 
    //preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Your code here.
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks my friend ,, could you explain the code to me more ?

Comment: Yes of course! When you click the second input the event bubbles to parent elements and trigger the every click handler.So, when you click your second input also your parent DIV will receive the click ! The code above will prevent that ! Let me know if that solves your problem.